# Add form to umbraco v6 pure razor view to call surface controller action passing ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I have a razor view that simply reads in querystring values to pass parameters to a class library that returns collections of things, hence

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "LayoutDefaultView.cshtml";
}
@{ 
    if (Request.QueryString["newCust"] == "true")
    {
         do stuff
    }
```

I cannot change the above code but I need to create new functionality in the above view so I can pass an ID to another view which is based based on a viewmodel, something like

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<NewSurfaceController>("newAction", FormMethod.Post, new {id = custId}))
```

How can I do this?   I know it is not best practice but this is a quick fix as I cannot change any of the legacy code

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, it looks like you just need to add your Surface Controller, and the new view.

In your existing view, you will need to call the new controller, so

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm(
    "PerformSomeAction", 
    "MyNewController", 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { id = custId }))
{
    @* Your form code and submit button goes here *@
}
```

Now for the controller itself. We must inherit Umbracos SurfaceController class.

```
public class MyNewController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PerformSomeAction(int id)
    {
        var model = new MyNewModel()
        {
            Id = id
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

You can then create a new view for the surface controller, which you will be able to use with your strongly typed model.

```
@model MyNewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h1>The ID is @Model.Id.ToString()</h1>
```